# GridView OnclickListener doesnt work if there is an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview, android-edittext

I am using a gridview and the view in each square is a relative layout. The onitemclicklistener will not work if there is an edittext or button in the relativelayout.

It is not a problem with the adapter because I tested the onclicklistener without any edittext or buttons and it worked.

How do I make it work with an edit text and button?

Itemlayout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivcustom1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selectexcercise" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvcustomsets1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivcustom1"
        android:textColor="#3498db"
        android:text="Sets:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvcustomreps1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvcustomsets1"
        android:textColor="#3498db"
        android:text="Reps:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etcustom2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvcustomreps1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvcustomreps1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivcustom1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Enter Reps"
        android:textColor="#3498db"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etcustom1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvcustomsets1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvcustomsets1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etcustom2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Enter Sets"
        android:textColor="#3498db"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivcustom1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etcustom1"
        android:background="#3498db" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvcustomreps1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etcustom1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvcustomreps1"
        android:background="@drawable/stretchesclicked"
        android:text="Note"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just in case here is the onitemclicklistener

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("The position is" + position);
        }
    });
```

and the adapter

```
 public class CustomWorkoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomWorkoutAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        RelativeLayout RL = rList.get(position);

        return RL;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Itemlayout,add this:

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

try it.

Comment: when I touch the imageview its as if I touched the button and the button focuses. also it causes the edittexts to become unfocusable. But the onclick listener works...

Answer (score 0):

ListViews are not made for that.  If you want an item to be editable, you handle the ListView.OnItemClickListener() event and have a Dialog pop-up that allows them to edit it.

Comment: it's a gridview... But I am assuming the same thing goes for that so I will try it out.

Comment: They are functionally the same in most ways.